# regular expression problem

Tags: regex, greedy

[image: demo]
i'm test a regular expression,i curious about the match result,

the symbol * is greendy,in my option,the result shuld only match 1 result,
like belows:

```
<script language=javascript>
ati('#', '../../../UpLoadFile/Product/20101010162153846.jpg', '加厚青色围脖');
}
</script>
<script language=javascript>
ati
```

but the result is not what i expect,any one could help me explain it,thank you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*` is greedy, but it's only matching `\s`, which means whitespace characters. If you want to match everything up to the last appearance of ati, use `.*` instead.

If this environment doesn't match newlines with ., maybe you can include them by matching on `(.|\n)*`

Comment: The usual way to make `.` match anything-including-newlines is to set the *dot-matches-all* switch (e.g. `/.*/s` or `(?s).*`--it's `s` in most flavors, but Ruby uses `m`).  In JavaScript, which has no *dot-matches-all* mode, it's best to use `[\s\S]*`.

Answer (score 1):

It can not match what you want because you are only matching the start of it.

Greedy gets you when you look for something arbitrary between 2 markers, and you get everything between the first and last, i.e.

```
/<p>.*<\/p>/
```

Usually, when you do that, you want all `p` elements. But without the ungreedy `.*?` or the `U` flag, you will get everything between the first and last instance.

Comment: So to pack this answer into a regex, I guess the poster probably wants `/<script language=javascript>\s*ati.*?</script>/`.